# On-demand virtual machine hosting

Tags: virtual-machine

Not sure if this counts as a software recommendation.

I need a virtual machine to run some raytracing software. It does not need a big hard disk or fast network connection. Just a really fast CPU (multi-core is okay) and maybe 8-16 GiB RAM. It does not need to be running 24/7. I would prefer a "pay as you go" plan, since I may be starting or stopping the VM at odd hours. I do not need a database, web server, etc. or other services running.

What are some good (cheap) solutions?

I tried Azure already. It was really easy to set up. The rate was $110.26 for 65.43 hours for the F16 (16 cores, 32 GiB RAM, ...) service. I feel comfortable with using this, except maybe the price.

Google's service seems cheaper maybe, especially if the VM "preemptible". I.e. Google will shut it down when their higher-paying customers need the load. This may be bad for me though.

Any other suggestions? If you could tell me *how* to sign up with said service, that would be great, because there are so many of them, and so many add-ons, that I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Digital Ocean

[DigitalOcean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com) provides virtual machine instances on-demand. You can manually create and stop/start an instance (a “Droplet”) in a minute, with an operating system at your disposal (either [**FreeBSD**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) or any of a few [**Linux**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) distros). [Through their API](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/), you can programmatically create/stop/start a Droplet as well.

The cost is hourly, with a monthly maximum. Cost starts at less than a US penny per hour, or more for more memory/processors/storage/traffic. Their standard offering with 8 gigs of memory costs over a US dime per hour, for 16 gigs almost a US quarter per hour. You probably want their "High-Memory" offerings with less cores and less storage, where 16 gigs costs US $0.18 per hour currently.

Optionally, you can pay for a chunk of storage separately, “SSD Block Storage”. Then join that storage to any VM that you startup and then later tear down (delete).

Lots of good documentation and [tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/) available.

## Heroku

[Heroku.com](https://www.heroku.com) is another provider of virtual computing environments on demand. In contrast to Digital Ocean, you get a managed environment already configured rather than a full OS on a virtual machine. Underneath, Heroku is powered by AWS (Amazon) the last I heard.

Comment: Actually, I need more cores and less memory. I can see DO's High Memory plan. Do they have a High CPU plan as well?

Comment: @posfan12 Don't think so. Digital Ocean tries to keep everything very simple and straightforward including their offerings and pricing. But I suggest contacting their salespeople to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Linode](https://www.linode.com) for a very long time, so I'll recommend looking at them.  I've never had an issue with the service that a mistake on my end didn't cause.  Their support folks bend over backwards to make you happy.

Storage is all SSD based.  Billing can be hourly, or fixed-rate monthly. For $80/mo or $0.12/hr you can get 12gb RAM, 6 cpu cores, almost 200gb storage, 8tb of transfer, and a 1gb/s network connection.  Need more? $0.96/hr gets you 20 cores, 80gb RAM, and 1.5tb storage.  Need even more? At $1.44 per hour (getting close to your Azure pricing) you can get a "high memory plan" with 200gb ram and 16 cpu cores.